# Validations problems when installing the application on Weblogic 12

Tags: weblogic, weblogic-10.x, weblogic12c, weblogic9.x, weblogic8.x

I have moved a Web application from Weblogic 9.2 to 12.1.2.0.0.
When I tried to Install the application through the Weblogic console, it gives me below error. I have searched the "fast-swap" text in every XML file in the Web Application but could not find a match.

Can someone please help me on this. Weblogic console gives me below error.

```
VALIDATION PROBLEMS WERE FOUND <2:4> problem: cvc-complex-type.2.3: Element 'fast-swap@http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-application' with element-only content type cannot have text content.
```

Answer (score 1):

Just found the culprit, founf weblogic-application.xml within the META-INF with below contents,

```
<weblogic-application>  
    <fast-swap>true</fast-swap>   
</weblogic-application>
```

So I had to correct it as below,

```
<weblogic-application>  
    <fast-swap>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
    </fast-swap>   
</weblogic-application>
```